# Fixed menu bar in Halcyonic theme (CSS)

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, responsive-design

How can modify CSS code to make the top header stay fixed so when I scroll up it stays fixed with a neat shadow? If you resize and look at the mobile responsive version you see what I mean.

Look here:
http://html5up.net/uploads/demos/halcyonic/twocolumn1.html

The code is downloadable here:
http://html5up.net/halcyonic/download

Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),  [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I would do this and have provided a link to all the code. I just don't know where to start?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some element style on the parent div:

```
<div id="skel-panels-pageWrapper" style="position: relative; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; -webkit-perspective: 500; -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out; transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out;" >
```

This inline style is stopping it from working for some reason. If you remove `-webkit-perspective: 500;` the following CSS should work.

```
#header-wrapper{
   position:fixed;
   width:100%;
   top:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#header-wrapper{
   position:fixed;
   width:100%;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   left:0;
}
```

Should do it...but its not happening.. i Tried on the site. May be some javascript function is interferring!!!

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am trying to figure out as well.

Comment: @dafmeister answer is right... if you can remove -webkit-perspective from the parent element the above css should work fine. If you/ theme is not using any sort of css 3d transforms then you can remove this property without anything breaking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following codes to #header-wrapper css:

```
#header-wrapper{ position:fixed; width:100% }
```

And add the following to the css file:

```
#content-wrapper #content{margin-top:155px;}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but still not working. Really puzzled by this.